# perl "or" error handling: multi-statement on error possible?

Tags: perl

This construct is pretty common in perl:

```
opendir (B,"/somedir") or die "couldn't open dir!";
```

But this does not seem to work:

```
opendir ( B, "/does-not-exist " ) or {
    print "sorry, that directory doesn't exist.\n";
    print "now I eat fugu.\n";
    exit 1;
};
```

Is it possible for the "or" error-handling to have more than one command?

Compiling the above:

```
# perl -c test.pl
syntax error at test.pl line 5, near "print"
syntax error at test.pl line 7, near "}"
test.pl had compilation errors.
```

Comment: Error prints should be sent to `STDERR`, and you should use `die` instead of `print`+`exit`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can always use [`do`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html):

```
opendir ( B, "/does-not-exist " ) or do {
    print "sorry, that directory doesn't exist.\n";
    print "now I eat fugu.\n";
    exit 1;
}
```

Or you can use if/unless:

```
unless (opendir ( B, "/does-not-exist " )) {
    print "sorry, that directory doesn't exist.\n";
    print "now I eat fugu.\n";
    exit 1;
}
```

Or you can swing together your own subroutine:

```
opendir ( B, "/does-not-exist " ) or fugu();

sub fugu {
    print "sorry, that directory doesn't exist.\n";
    print "now I eat fugu.\n";
    exit 1;
}
```

There is more than one way to do it.

Comment: The "more regular" doesn't work, for example, if one uses `open(my $B, ...)`.

Comment: @ikegami Well, it *does* work, it just won't be very productive. With global file handle, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: @TLP apart from the scope issue, why do you consider the "unless" solution not recommended?

Comment: @bill mostly because of scope.

Comment: `opendir ( B, "/does-not-exist " ) or do {
   print "sorry, that directory doesn't exist.\n";
   print "now I eat fugu.\n";
   exit 1;
};`
You are missing the ";" to end the instruction.

Answer (score -2):

Exception handling in Perl is done with *eval()*

```
eval {
    ...
} or do {
    ...Use $@ to handle the error...
};
```

Comment: `open` doesn't die, it just returns `undef`. There's nothing to catch using `eval`.